# Conditional renderings in JSX not working in CRA PROD build

Tags: reactjs

I am using Create React App. The code runs fine in the development server. But after I copied the build folder into remote server, the re-rendering stops working. In debug, it goes to the end of the render method, then the below message shows up in the console:

```
TypeError: d.delete is not a function    
at m (react-dom.production.min.js:126)    
at react-dom.production.min.js:130    
at u (react-dom.production.min.js:131)    
at d (react-dom.production.min.js:131)
```

Today I find that the error is related to using '&&', so if I replaced the logical && by using ternary operation with an empty span being added in the end, then the processing can move to next sub-component.

What confuses me is when the component got rendered the first time, there is no issue, only after I click a link/button which in turn triggers "setState" method, then the error shows up. Nevertheless, the code works fine in DEVELOPMENT server.  Please help.

Comment: can you add the source code in question?

Comment: Thank you for asking the question.  I reduced the code to a very minimum and the code turns out to be working.  So I was wrong here.  It seems our legacy library clashes with the react code. If I include the legacy library, then "delete is not a function" error message shows up.  If the library is excluded, the code works as expected. Thank you again for the help.